# Java 8 Stream Collectors - Collector to create a Map with objects in multiple buckets

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

The following code works and is readable but it seems to me I have intermediate operations that feel like they shouldn't be necessary.  I've written this simplified version as the actual code is part of a much larger process.

I've got a `Collection` of `Widget`, each with a name and multiple types (indicated by constants of the `WidgetType` enum).  These multiple types are gettable as a `Stream<WidgetType>` though, if necessary, I could return those as some other type.  (For various reasons, it is *strongly desirable* that these be returned as a `Stream<WidgetType>` because of how these widgets are used later in the actual code.)

These widgets are added to an `EnumMap<WidgetType, List<Widget>>` which is, later, translated into an `EnumMap<WidgetType, Widget[]>`.

If each `Widget` only had a single `WidgetType`, this would be a trivial solve but, since any Widget could have 1 or more types, I am tripping all over myself with the syntax of the `Collectors.groupingBy()` method (and its overloads).

Here's the code example, again, fully functional and gives me the exact result I need.

```
class StackOverFlowExample {

    private final Map<WidgetType, Widget[]> widgetMap = new EnumMap<>(WidgetType.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) { new StackOverFlowExample(); }

    StackOverFlowExample() {
        Collection<Widget> widgetList = getWidgetsFromWhereverWidgetsComeFrom();

        {
            final Map<WidgetType, List<Widget>> intermediateMap = new EnumMap<>(WidgetType.class);
            widgetList.forEach(w ->
                    w.getWidgetTypes().forEach(wt -> {
                        intermediateMap.putIfAbsent(wt, new ArrayList<>());
                        intermediateMap.get(wt).add(w);
                    })
            );
            intermediateMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> widgetMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().toArray(new Widget[0])));
        }

        Arrays.stream(WidgetType.values()).forEach(wt -> System.out.println(wt + ": " + Arrays.toString(widgetMap.get(wt))));
    }

    private Collection<Widget> getWidgetsFromWhereverWidgetsComeFrom() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new Widget("1st", WidgetType.TYPE_A, WidgetType.TYPE_B),
                new Widget("2nd", WidgetType.TYPE_A, WidgetType.TYPE_C),
                new Widget("3rd", WidgetType.TYPE_A, WidgetType.TYPE_D),
                new Widget("4th", WidgetType.TYPE_C, WidgetType.TYPE_D)
        );
    }

}
```

This outputs:

```
TYPE_A: [1st, 2nd, 3rd]
TYPE_B: [1st]
TYPE_C: [2nd, 4th]
TYPE_D: [3rd, 4th]
```

For completeness sake, here's the `Widget` class and the `WidgetType` enum:

```
class Widget {

    private final String       name;
    private final WidgetType[] widgetTypes;

    Widget(String n, WidgetType ... wt) { name = n; widgetTypes = wt; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public Stream<WidgetType> getWidgetTypes() { return Arrays.stream(widgetTypes).distinct(); }

    @Override public String toString() { return name; }
}

enum WidgetType { TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE_C, TYPE_D }
```

Any ideas on a better way to execute this logic are welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO, the key is to convert a `Widget` instance to a `Stream<Pair<WidgetType, Widget>>` instance. Once we have that, we can `flatMap` a stream of widgets and collect on the resulting stream. Of course we don't have `Pair` in Java, so have to use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` instead.

```
widgets.stream()
       // Convert a stream of widgets to a stream of (type, widget)
       .flatMap(w -> w.getTypes().map(t->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(t, w)))
       // Grouping by the key, and do additional mapping to get the widget
       .collect(groupingBy(e->e.getKey(),
                mapping(e->e.getValue, 
                        collectingAndThen(toList(), l->l.toArray(new Widget[0])))));
```

P.S. this is an occasion where IntelliJ's suggestion doesn't shorten a lambda with method reference.

Comment: Thanks, @JornVernee. Edited.

Comment: `Collectors.mapping()` is the part I was missing.  The `collectingAndThen()` solution is a bonus, too.  (I had pretty much resigned myself to requiring that extra step.)  Nailed it, Luke.  +1 all day.  Thanks a million!  :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit convoluted, but it produces the same output, not necessarily in the same order. It uses a static import of `java.util.stream.Collectors.*`.

```
widgetMap = widgetList.stream()
        .flatMap(w -> w.getWidgetTypes().map(t -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(t, w)))
        .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, collectingAndThen(mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toSet()), s -> s.stream().toArray(Widget[]::new))));
```

Output on my machine:

```
TYPE_A: [1st, 3rd, 2nd]
TYPE_B: [1st]
TYPE_C: [2nd, 4th]
TYPE_D: [3rd, 4th]
```